# Deploy using alchemy or remix

Tags: web3js, remix, alchemy

Initially I interact with my smart contract using remix but when it comes to interact on my website. I face some issues so that I deploy my contract to alchemy.

Two questions confuse me.

1. can I regard Alchemy as backend service which can be called from my app
2. can I deploy my contract using remix and still it can be used in my frontend website?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Alchemy is a service that allows you have rapid access to the blockchain while giving you analytical feedback. Alchemy can be injected into a smart contract, a Dapp, & your can even boost your metamask's performance by injecting an HTTP API key into the RPC URL :]
2. YES SIR! Its does not matter if you deploy with code or a GUI, it all goes to the same place & any smart contract can be interacted with when you use front-end libraries like Ethers.js web3.js.

Answer (score 0):

To add on here, [Alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com) is a developer platform. That means it provides a suite of developer toolings and abstractions including JSON RPC APIs across all major chains, an ethers.js SDK, and a library of enhanced APIs like their NFT APIs. OpenSea, Aave, and The Graph all use Alchemy as their blockchain infrastructure provider. Alchemy doesn't just provide an API key that serves as a RPC endpoint to connect to various blockchains, but also has lots of tooling to read and write easier to blockchains.

When deploying smart contracts, Alchemy can be used in conjunction with things like Metamask, Solidity, HardHat, and ethers.js. Or Remix. An example of this is in Alchemy's [beginner smart contract tutorial](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/hello-world-smart-contract).

Remix is an online all-integrated IDE that lets you test, deploy and execute smart contracts from the comfort of your browser tab. If you decide to use Remix, Alchemy can help as the RPC endpoint to accurately and reliably communicate with the your selededed blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the contract write + deployment process in case it's helpful:

1. Add and compile the contract code into Remix
2. Add your chosen RPC provider (e.g., Alchemy, Moralis, etc) as a network in Metamask. You do this by clicking on "Add a network" in Metamask. I usually call this new network: "[Network name] via [RPC provider name]". Get the URL by logging into your RPC provider dashboard and grabbing the HTTP API key. See picture below
3. If it's a Ethereum testnet, get testETH from faucets to add to your Metamask. Here are two of the most popular faucets: [Sepolia](https://www.sepoliafaucet.com) or [Goerli](https://www.goerlifaucet.com)
4. Connect Metamask to Remix. If you're having issues, remove another connected wallet first before connecting Metamask
5. Deploy your contract by choosing the "Injected Provider" as the deployment environment. This injected provider comes from your selected provider in Metamask. Make sure the correct network through the external RPC provider's endpoint is selected in Metamask

--

[Here is a Remix tutorial with more details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U15XXqv8FmU)

Comment: If you work for Alchemy you should disclose the affiliation https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/promotion. Otherwise the answers could be flagged as spam. Also, avoid copying and pasting the same answer multiple times. Instead you could flag the questions as duplicates.